# Сделать выпадающий список меню WinApi

Tags: winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, зачем нужна функция CreatePopupMenu ? То есть я понимаю зачем, чтобы, как раз создавать выпадающий список в меню. Но выпадающий в список в меню создается без проблем и без использования CreatePopupMenu, вот два варианта, один с CreatePopupMenu, другой только с AppendMenu:

```
 HMENU My_Main_Menu_Bar = CreateMenu();
            HMENU hPopMenuFile = CreatePopupMenu();

            AppendMenu(My_Main_Menu_Bar, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopMenuFile, "File");
            AppendMenu(My_Main_Menu_Bar, MF_STRING, 1000, "Help");
            
            AppendMenu(hPopMenuFile, MF_STRING , 1001, "Open");
            AppendMenu(hPopMenuFile, MF_STRING , 1002, "Close");

            SetMenu(hwnd, My_Main_Menu_Bar);
            SetMenu(hwnd, hPopMenuFile);
```

и

```
HMENU My_Main_Menu_Bar = CreateMenu();
```

HMENU My_File_Menu = CreateMenu();
HMENU My_Help_Menu = CreateMenu();

Добавим кнопки в само меню:
BOOL My_bool_AppendMenu1 = AppendMenuA(My_Main_Menu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)My_File_Menu, "File");
BOOL My_bool_AppendMenu2 = AppendMenuA(My_Main_Menu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)My_Help_Menu, L"Help");

Добавим выпадающий список в кнопку File:

BOOL My_bool_Append_to_File1 = AppendMenuA(My_File_Menu, MF_STRING, NULL, "Open");
BOOL My_bool_Append_to_File2 = AppendMenuA(My_File_Menu, MF_STRING, NULL, "Close");

SetMenu(hWnd, My_Main_Menu);

Как делать правильнее с точки зрения эффективности?

Comment: Aziz Umarov, а если мне не нужно контекстное меню при нажатии правой кнопки мыши. А нужно простое вверху файла.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте меню как на нажатии правой кнопки мыши. Думаю придется использовать немного подумать.

> The application can add the new menu to an existing menu, or it can
> display a shortcut menu by calling the TrackPopupMenuEx or
> TrackPopupMenu functions.

Приложение может добавить меню в существующем меню либо показать всплывающее меню вызовом TrackPopupMenuEx или TrackPopupMenu

Подробнее [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createpopupmenu)